# Does startForeground update the old notification with the same id?

Tags: android, service, notifications, overwrite

When i first call `startForeground(NOTIFY_ID, notification)` (called from a Service) everything works fine.

Later I want to update some views of the Notification and then I call startForeground again in hope that this will just overwrite/update the old Notification because of its ID. But then the notification turns to this:

[image]

The notification seems to be empty and just floating over all other notifications. In other words: The notification just messes up.

My Question is: Does startForeground even updates the old notification?

Comment: After a restart of my phone it suddenly works fine. Still interested in why this happens/why this could happen. I don't want to have the users of my app have this problem even once.